# Android: Trouble opening a user selected CSV or EXCEL file

Tags: java, android, csv, android-studio

I'm creating an app and I need the user to be able to import data into the local Room database on the device. I'm utilizing the `startActivityForResult(...)` method to get a response from the `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` shown here:

```
Intent intent = new Intent().setType("*/*").setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), GET_FILE_INTENT_CODE);
```

After asking the user to specify the layout of the file that is to be imported and converting it into a `ImportStrategy` I pass both the `strategy` and the `Uri` received in the `onActivityResult(...)` to my `importData` method

```
    void importData(Uri data, ImportStrategy strategy) {
        try {
            File csvFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + data.getPath());
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFile.getAbsolutePath()));

            String[] nextLine;
            List<RainfallRecord> records = new ArrayList<>();

            while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                records.add(getRecord(nextLine, strategy));
            }

            db.recordDao().insertAll(records);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "Error loading file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "Error processing file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

The issue that I'm running into is when it gets to the line where it creates the CSVReader I get a `FileNotFoundException`
Stack Trace:

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/document/1945 (No such file or directory)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:231)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:165)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:112)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
W/System.err:     at ekshore.net.raintracker.MainActivity.importData(MainActivity.java:351)
W/System.err:     at ekshore.net.raintracker.MainActivity.lambda$customStrategy$11(MainActivity.java:406)
W/System.err:     at ekshore.net.raintracker.-$$Lambda$MainActivity$A7AYI1UOo4MNVQeFvopgj2wHPMM.onClick(Unknown Source:11)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

The URI That is coming back is `content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/1945` The `1945` at the end should be `Rain(2018).xlsx`

In all of the research I have done on this issue, I have seen that there are issues with loading files from URI types of `content`. But all the fixes that I have seen have been specific to media files (either images or audio), not more data oriented files like this. And when I have tried to mimick other solutions that make use of `ContentResolver` I have not been able to figure it out.

If someone could give me a hand and help me figure this out I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more research I stumbled across this [blog](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html) And discovered that I had been trying to go about it the wrong way. The way that I needed to open the file is not through the `File` object, which requires a file path. Instead I needed to use the `ContentResolver` to create and `InputStream` and get the data that way, the code ended up looking like this:

```
try {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = this.getContentResolver();

        InputStream inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(data);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream).useDelimiter("\n");

        String nextLine = scanner.nextLine();
        List<RainfallRecord> records = new ArrayList<>();

        if (nextLine.matches("^[A-Za-z]"));
            nextLine = scanner.nextLine();

        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String[] rainData = nextLine.split(",");
            nextLine = scanner.nextLine();
            records.add(getRecord(rainData, strategy));
        }

        db.recordDao().insertAll(records);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "Error processing file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

The`if (nextLine.matches("^[A-Za-z]"));` is chekcing to see if there is header information and skip it if there is.